# ReadProcessMemory() returns 0 for static addresses

Tags: c++, visual-c++, readprocessmemory

What I try to do is to read a static address that's pointing to a dynamic adress that holds some value. But if I try to read the static address it always returns 0. The only way for it to be read is if I attach a debugger to the dynamic address in cheat engine. However I have no problem reading it with only reading from the dynamic address.

```
DWORD address = 0x74EA46D8;
int value = 0;
int new_address = 0;
DWORD pid;
HWND hwnd;
hwnd = FindWindow(NULL,L"HackMe.exe");
if(!hwnd) {
    cout <<"Window not found!\n";
    cin.get();
} else {
    GetWindowThreadProcessId(hwnd,&pid);

    HANDLE phandle = OpenProcess(PROCESS_VM_READ,0,pid);
    if(!phandle) {
        cout <<"Could not get handle!\n";
        cin.get();
    } else {
        while(1) {
            ReadProcessMemory(phandle,(void*)address,&new_address,sizeof(new_address),0);
            cout << new_address << "\n"; //Always print 0
            //int new_address = 0x2ECA40B0; //This works if I uncomment this
            ReadProcessMemory(phandle,(void*)new_address,&value,sizeof(value),0);
```

I even tried getting debug privelege, but that didn't do anything. I have no clue on what the problem is since I'm very new to C++. Any help is appreciated.

Thank you.

**Edit**

GetLastError() returns 0 at first, then it returns 299

**Edit 2**

```
BOOL x = ReadProcessMemory(phandle,(void*)address,&new_address,sizeof(new_address),0);
cout << x << " " << GetLastError() << "\n";
```

returns

```
1 0
1 299
1 299
1 299
```

and so on

**Edit 3**
Bytes read is 4.

**Edit 4**

Just to clarify.

Reading directly from 0x74EA46D8 with ReadProcessMemory() returns 0.

If I open up cheat engine and add the address 0x74EA46D8 points to to the address list. Then right click on it and press "Find out what access this address" it can be read all of a sudden. Enabling SeDebugPrivelege does nothing.

The dynamic address can be read as normal, without having debug privelege(as long as I manually type the address for it or cheat engine debugs the address so the static address can be read)

It's structured in this way:

static address pointing to the address I try to read, this return 0 as the "new address" unless see above.

dynamic address, containing the value I'm trying to read. This reads just fine if I define the dynamic address manually. But if I don't it fails since new_address is 0, unless see above.

**Edit 5**

Finally I found out the problem, the previous address was wrong. That address was part of cheat engine and the real address was 0x013CD878 with an offset of 0x4B0. That was the reason why it didn't work unless I debugged it.

But I hope others will learn from my mistake :P

Comment: What makes you think that `0x74EA46D8` is right?

Comment: It is read just fine if I use cheat engine to debug the address it's holding

Comment: What's the return value from ReadProcessMemory, and if it's false what does GetLastError say?

Comment: So the first call to ReadProcessMemory has a GetLastError of 0, and the second is 299, or is it before and after the first call?

Comment: I put GetLastError after "ReadProcessMemory(phandle,(void*)address,&new_address,sizeof(new_address),0);", first time(first time run after program started) the error code is 0, and ReadProcessMemory returns 0. Second time and everytime after that GetLastError return 299, and ReadProcessMemory return 0.

Comment: Are you sure `ReadProcessMemory` *returns* zero? You're not using the return value in the code you've shown. You're using the variable that you asked it to fill, but since that variable started out holding zero, you can't really know whether `ReadProcessMemory` is reading anything at all. Declare a variable to receive the function's return value: `BOOL x = ReadProcessMemory(...)`. Then inspect *that* value, along with the result of `GetLastError`: `cout << x << ' ' << GetLastError()`.

Comment: Oops, you can tell I'm not that good at this :P

Comment: And don't call GetLastError when it returns TRUE.

Comment: I assume you already looked up error 299 and saw that it's "ERROR_PARTIAL_COPY: Only part of a ReadProcessMemory or WriteProcessMemory request was completed.", right?

Comment: Also, have you tried calling VirtualProtectEx to (a) verify that the memory is readable, and (b) make it readable if not? Or calling VirtualQueryEx and printing out all the details to see what kind of page you're dealing with, etc.?

Comment: @abarnert, no I haven't. I have no clue on how to do that though :P

Comment: Well, look at the documentation for those two functions; it's pretty obvious how to call them. If you have a problem using them, you can ask about it here, or on the MSDN quasi-wiki-thingy.

Comment: Meanwhile: Are you absolutely sure that both your app and the target app are x86, neither is x64?

Comment: My system is 64-bit windows 7. The app is 32-bit.

Comment: What should I put as "LPCVOID lpAddress"? 0x74EA46D8 doesn't seem to work.

Comment: I guess the address is wrong, 0x74EA46D8 would hardly be an address of a normal application. You may be inspecting an address of a loaded module instead of the application thread itself

Comment: Maybe. But the program can read it. Just not without cheat engine activated.

Comment: I'm beginning to think this is an address in cheat engine, or the debugger.

Answer (score 1):

Aren't you reading from different addresses? `address != new_address`. `(void*)address` - is the address where you start reading from.

Comment: address == static address,

new_address == dynamic address -- This one reads just fine if I define it

Comment: Is it static address of a function in system DLL? Judging by `address` it is somewhere there.

Comment: Not sure, but why can I read it when cheat engine debug the address it's pointing to?

Comment: @thabubble Could you check if `ReadProcessMemory` returns FALSE? If it does then you can call [GetLastError](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms679360(v=vs.85).aspx). I assume that read fails and new_address simply has the value that you assigned it earlier.

Comment: @thabubble OK, can you also pass non null lpNumberOfBytesRead to see how many bytes are read? You could also add checks as [described here](http://www.gamehacking.com/index.php?/topic/10125-readprocessmemory-limitations/).

Comment: @thabubble Also 299 means: `ERROR_PARTIAL_COPY
299 (0x12B)
Only part of a ReadProcessMemory or WriteProcessMemory request was completed.`

Comment: Thanks for telling me, I couldn't find anything about 299 :P

Comment: The address is supposed to be 4 bytes holding the dynamic address in hex. The dynamic address is 4 bytes containing an int

Comment: Hex is just a notation. You see that RPM returns 299 error code which means incomplete read, so it is natural to see how incomplete it is. Last argument to the function can be used to return number of bytes that were read.

Comment: thabubble: How could you not be able to find anything about 299? The list of system error codes is only two links from any page in MSDN, and if you google "error code 299" it's the second link (and the first is a silly about.com copy of the same information).

Comment: Well, my googling skills are less than bad. so.... Well now I know what it means at least :D

Comment: OK, then do that search now and bookmark the page. Also bookmark the top-level MSDN search page, and probably the Debugging Reference page. You will need to be able to find all of these repeatedly.

Comment: I tried to figure out what resides at this address but couldn't find anything. Try running [this tool](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/dd535533.aspx), maybe 0 is correct value. Why are you so sure that it cannot be 0. Still in my original response I wrote that you're reading from 2 different addresses it is perfectly normal to get different results. Moreover 0x2.. is very likely to be allocated to the process itself (not system lib) which will not require any additional permissions to read from there. Have you tried checking permissions?

Comment: I have tried checking permissions. I know it's not 0, since it's supposed to be 50, well the dynamic address should be. The static address is the one returning 0, and that should be the address to the dynamic address. Check out edit 4 where I explained it a bit more.